# Read tsv file from jar

Tags: java, classpath

I have a tsv file in project's class path which i try to read using the getResource() method. My code is this:

```
    File file=new File(ClassName.class.getResource("/folder/myfile.tsv").getFile());
    CSVReader reader=new CSVReader(new FileReader(file),'\t');
```

So when i run the code i get this message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \folder\myfile.tsv (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: What is the full path to the file?

Comment: The folder is inside the projects's src direcrory.

Comment: Is it inside the resource folder?

Comment: I don't have a resource folder, only packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use getResource to get a reference to a file that is packaged with your java classes because the resource maybe inside a JAR or WAR file at runtime.

Use the following instead:

```
InputStream is = ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/folder/myfile.tsv");
CSVReader reader=new CSVReader(is, '\t', StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```